# Set data in Custom view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-view

I am building a custom view that makes an HTTP request to a Rest API every 6 seconds and displays a different question with its possible answers. A Buff in this case would be the object that contains the question and its possible answers.

Right now, the views are injected, but, when setting the data (see setAnswer function), the first view shows the text from the last element of the answer list. The rest of the views don't show any text.

**Buff object received from API**

With this data, I should show a question with 3 possible answers: "No goals!", "One goal!", "Two or more" in that order.

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "author": {
            "first_name": "Ronaldo"
        },
        "question": {
            "id": 491,
            "title": "Kaio Jorge has 4 goals this tournament – I think he will score again today. What do you think?"
        },
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1163,
                "buff_id": 0,
                "title": "No goals!"
            },
            {
                "id": 1164,
                "buff_id": 0,
                "title": "One goal!"
            },
            {
                "id": 1165,
                "buff_id": 0,
                "title": "Two or more!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**This is how is displayed at the moment**
[First element displays the text from the 3rd answer and the other two are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLgJB.jpg)

**BuffView.kt (my custom view)**

```
class BuffView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null): LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val apiErrorHandler = ApiErrorHandler()
    private val getBuffUseCase = GetBuffUseCase(apiErrorHandler)

    private var buffIdCount = 1

    private val buffView: View

    init {
        buffView = inflate(context, R.layout.buff_view, this)
    }

    fun start() {
        getBuff()
    }

    private fun getBuff() {
        getBuffUseCase.invoke(buffIdCount.toLong(), object : UseCaseResponse<Buff> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: Buff) {
                displayBuff(result)
            }

            override fun onError(errorModel: ErrorModel?) {
                //Todo: show error toast
                Log.e("AppDebug", "onError: errorModel $errorModel")
            }
        })

        val delay = 6000L
        RepeatHelper.repeatDelayed(delay) {
            if (buffIdCount < 5) {
                buffIdCount++
                getBuff()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun displayBuff(buff: Buff) {
        setQuestion(buff.question.title)
        setAuthor(buff.author)
        setAnswer(buff.answers)
        setCloseButton()
        buffView.visibility = VISIBLE
    }

    private fun setQuestion(questionText: String) {
        question_text.text = questionText
    }

    private fun setAuthor(author: Buff.Author) {
        val firstName = author.firstName
        val lastName = author.lastName
        sender_name.text = "$firstName $lastName"

        Glide.with(buffView)
            .load(author.image)
            .into(sender_image)
    }

    private fun setAnswer(answers: List<Buff.Answer>) {
        val answersContainer = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.answersContainer)
        answersContainer.removeAllViews()
        for(answer in answers) {
            val answerView: View = LayoutInflater.from(answersContainer.context).inflate(
                R.layout.buff_answer,
                answersContainer,
                false
            )
            answer_text?.text = answer.title

            answersContainer.addView(answerView)
        }
    }

    private fun setCloseButton() {
        buff_close.setOnClickListener {
            buffView.visibility = GONE
        }
    }
}
```

**buff_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/buff_sender"/>
    <include layout="@layout/buff_question"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/answersContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**buff_answer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/light_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer_image"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_generic_answer"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/test_color_dark"
        tools:text="The keeper's right"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `invalidate()` after `addView()` to tell the View it should re-render. Also you need to set text on `answerView`, so the method should look like this:

```kotlin
private fun setAnswer(answers: List<Buff.Answer>) {
        val answersContainer = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.answersContainer)
        answersContainer.removeAllViews()
        for(answer in answers) {
            val answerView: View = LayoutInflater.from(answersContainer.context).inflate(
                R.layout.buff_answer,
                answersContainer,
                false
            )
            answerView.answer_text?.text = answer.title

            answersContainer.addView(answerView)
        }
        invalidate() // or invalidateSelf()
    }
```

Another thing is that it's a very bad practice to call your api from the custom view. Executing the usecase should be on the ViewModel/Presenter etc. level. Then the buffs should be provided to the Fragment/Activity and then set in the CustomView. You are also not cancelling the request in some view-destroying callback like `onDetachedFromWindow()` which can lead to memory leaks

Comment: Thank you so much Mariusz, the problem was that I wasn't setting the text on answerView. I know that I should not execute the usecase on the view, but, what I am building is a library for a custom view, so there are no activities or Fragments, so I guess I can't (or it doesn't make much sense) use a ViewModel?

Comment: So you can mark it as accepted answer ;) Also consider moving the useCase to the ViewModel/Presenter level so you will have clean data flow across the app and it will be much more testable :)

Comment: Can I still use a ViewModel even though I am not going to have an Activity or a Fragment  on the library? I asked this question about it a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080084/architecture-for-a-custom-view-library-android

Comment: Okay, that changes the context of the question :) Let me answer that in this question :)

Comment: @HelenC take a look into the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080084/architecture-for-a-custom-view-library-android , I gave my 5 cents into that :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the same view more than once without recreating its new variable, this is not as simple as one would think.

```
private fun setAnswer(answers: List<Buff.Answer>) {
    val answersContainer = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.answersContainer)
    var viewlist = ArrayList()
    answersContainer.removeAllViews()
    for(answer in answers) {
        val answerView: View = LayoutInflater.from(answersContainer.context).inflate(
            R.layout.buff_answer,
            answersContainer,
            false
        )
        answer_text?.text = answer.title
        viewlist.add(answerView)
        
    }
    for(view in viewlist)
        answersContainer.addView(view)
}
```